# Show that two isometries induce the same linear mapping

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

How can I show that two isometries $F_1,F_2 : M \to M$ which agree at point $p$ and induce the same linear mapping from $T_pM$ agree on a neighborhood on $p$?

I am happy about a hint or an idea of how to approach it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use that an isometry sends geodesics to geodesics, and check what happens to geodesics emanating from $p$.